# Strange behaviour with Dropdown List and IE8

Tags: javascript, asp.net, css

I have a strange behavour with IE 8 and a dropdownlist. The issue happen just on one DDL which displays title.
To give you an example I have a selection of{Mr,Ms,Mrs,Sir,Lady ....} if by mistake I select Miss instead of Mrs, the ddl continue to persist the Miss and doesn't allow me to select another title.

this issue isn't reproduced on another browser and I was wondering if you have ever had something of the sort.

It is unlikely to be cause by Javascript or css as there are other ddl with the same class. is there any explanation for this behaviour.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

This type of problem is typically caused by invalid html markup somewhere in your doc.  Try to validate the page and see if you have any problems you can't see.

Comment: Hi, what do you mean by validating the page? Thanks